# Wide column with Bootstrap and Isotope

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I have a project listing where I use Isotope and Bootstrap to show our projects. I have four columns, so each project spans three columns (`.col-md-3`). For the highlighted projects, I tried setting `.col-md-6` for this, and it works very nicely for all items not as first child. When setting double the grid size on the first item child, the layout fails.

Has anyone had this issue before? I've found this Isotope/Bootstrap code from somewhere else, that had exactly the same issue. Try removing `.col-md-6` from first child to any other, and it works perfectly, but never on the first child..

http://www.bootply.com/YaqDZBusnG

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
$(window).load(function() { ...js ...
```

on isotope function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, although the problem remained after trying this.